# Do moderators know who downvotes?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

Do moderators know who downvotes?

[This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703/downvoting-only-for-personal-preference-to-the-op) is a related question.

Comment: To the downvoters. I deleted almost all my answers to my questions to cater for you. However, some of them were recovered by some moderators.

Comment: Why don't you ask about upvotes too?

Comment: @MakotoKato Your answers are fine, and deleting them was inappropriate. The issue isn't your answers themselves, but how you go about composing them.

Comment: You didn't *delete* the answers, you edited them into vandalized oblivion. You don't need to be a moderator to rollback such edits, you just need enough rep.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You have been objecting me to answer my questions.
Now, are you going to obeject me to cater for you?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin One can't delete more than 5 answers in one day. So I deleted the contents.

Comment: Had I thought that trying to explain to you once again that I have no problem with you answering your own questions would be fruitful, I would do that. Alas, I don't think that would help. I simply point out that you asked several questions regarding downvotes. Why haven't you asked about upvotes as well?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin In case you wonder why I stop deleting my answers, it's because I was warned by a moderater that it was highly frowned upon.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Please don't pretend that you had no problem with my answering my questions.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm awfully sorry that I could not delete my answers completely.
I was stopped doing so by a moderator.
I encourage you to open a meta thread if you have any objection to my stopping the deletion.

Comment: @AlexBecker Some people(for example Arturo Magidin) said that I was using this site only for selfish purpose by answering my own questions. A professor said he didn't like an OP answering his(the OP's) own question. Another professor also said indirectly that he didn't like some type of self-answering, perhaps like the ones I was doing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "Why haven't you asked about upvotes as well?" I don't think I have anything to ask about them.
What do you expect me to ask?

Comment: Well, for someone that appears to be indifferent to reputation, I would expect you to ask about voting in an indifferent way. For example, is it okay to *vote* not based on mathematical content alone, rather than asking about *downvoting*, and similarly can the moderators know who *voted* and not just *downvoted*...

Comment: @AsafKaragila You seem to misunderstand. I'm asking a *general* question.
This is *not a personal* question.
If people downvote freely just because they don't like an OP, the reputation system doesn't work well. I notice that people tend to upvote just because an OP is a famous mathematician.
This is problematic but not so serious as the former.

Comment: No disrespect to the users of M.SE, but I don't know if there are many people here who qualify as a *famous mathematician*.

Comment: "the reputation system doesn't work well" - from [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation), "Reputation is a rough measurement of **how much the community trusts you**; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you're talking about." It's a measure of trust, not a measure of correctness. If you get downvoted sufficiently enough, you get low rep, and that correlates with people not having sufficient trust in whatever you're producing...

Comment: @Chris Taylor It's just an example. It also applies to a member with high reputations. In short, somewhat authoritative members.

Comment: @J.M. Each reputation should be voted only for the quality of a post. The OP's past behavior, good or bad, is irrelevant.

Comment: @MakotoKato You can talk about what *should* be the case until you're blue in the face, but what actually *is* the case is that nobody has to give reasons for their votes, and they are free to up- or down-vote for whatever reason they like. Anomalous voting patterns are [removed automatically](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/downvoted-by-another-user-for-the-wrong-reasons/1721#1721) by the system, so you there's no need to worry about personal vendettas/hero worship or the like.

Comment: Makoto, maybe so, but here we are. Again, if you really truly believe that your math is sound, then you shouldn't have to worry about downvotes; as @Chris already said, any voting anomalies are easily caught.

Comment: I'm not so nervous about downvotes(nor upvotes). I was just curious.

Comment: Temporary comment: see here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13381/should-experienced-users-be-held-for-higher-standards-when-posting-questions and the comment discussions.

Answer (score 21):

From [this meta.SO thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15942):

> Volunteer moderators have very limited access to voting information. The only voting information we can really see is related to anomalous voting patterns. This makes it easier for us to spot sock puppet accounts. We can't see specific votes cast on each question and answer by individual users.

See also [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128074) and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85529) and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95603).

Answer (score 19):

No, we do not. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 12):

No, such voting information is kept secret.

See also:  List of [Moderator Privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role/75192#75192).